# I tried running a python file in terminal on Visual Studio code, but it keeps giving me synthax error

Tags: python-3.x, input, visual-studio-code, terminal, notepad

```
print("Hi!")
name = input("what's your name? ")

print("It's nice to meet you,", name)
answer = input("Are you enjoying the course? ")

if answer =="Yes":
print("That's good to hear!")
else:
print("Oh no! That makes me sad!")
```

Above is the code but it keeps giving this syntax error below

```
 Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32   
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> & C:/Users/gbemi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/gbemi/Desktop/exercise files/chap01/01_03.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/gbemi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/gbemi/Desktop/exercise files/chap01/01_03.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I already went to files-preferences-settings to check the path, its correct. What is the issue please, I'm a newbie programmer.

Comment: you need to indent the print statements. and in your error part, you're already in the Python command line.   type ```quit()``` and then run the command ```C:/Users/gbemi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/gbemi/Desktop/exercise files/chap01/01_03.py"```

Answer (score 0):

Give proper indentation to the code. Then only it'll work.

Like this:

```
print("Hi!") 

name = input("what's your name? ")

print("It's nice to meet you,", name) 

answer = input("Are you enjoying the course? ")

if answer =="Yes": 

       print("That's good to hear!") 

else: 

       print("Oh no! That makes me sad!")
```